# Stop build only on errors of an external tool, not on warnings

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a project with a rather complex building process, I need to pass some generated files through a tool that generates some output on `stdout` from `stdin`.

The corresponding recipe is:

```
out-file: in-file
    @tool < $< > $@
```

(Actually, the names are generic, not static, but that's not the point here)

My problem is that this tool returns 1 on warnings and 2 on errors, and I want to stop **only** on errors. The way the recipe is written above, `make` will stop on warnings, and if I write:

```
out-file: in-file
    @-tool < $< > $@
```

Then it will **not** stop on errors.

How can I achieve this behavior, preferably using only make ?

[Manual reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html#Errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually catch the error and only exit with an error if the code you care about is the return code.

Something like:

```
@tool < $< > $@; [ $$? -ne 2 ]
```

or to be more exact:

```
@tool < $< > $@; ret=$$?; [ $$ret -eq 0] || [ $$ret -eq 1 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this assumes bash, doesn't it ?

Comment: I don't believe so. Though it might (and probably does) assume `sh`-derivation as opposed to `csh`-derivation. But the idea is the main point.

Comment: Yes, excuse me, I wasn't clear enough ;-) What I meant is that this will not work on Windows OSes (unless MSYS or similar). That's why I asked for a pure-make solution. But maybe it is not possible.

Comment: You should be able to do the same with `%ERRORLEVEL%` or whatever on Windows I believe. Again, the point was the mechanism. And no, you cannot do this with make alone since make is only checking success vs. failure.

Comment: I probably missed something, I tried to implement your answer but using `@ret=$(ls); echo "ret=-$ret-"` as recipe gives me `-et-`. And replacing with `$(ret)` gives an empty content (although `echo $?` on the shell gives me `0`). I also tried with `@ret=$(shell ls); echo "ret=-$(ret)-"` (the differences are unclear for me), but this generates an error. Did I miss something?

Comment: @kebs No, I just forgot the context. Sorry about that. For a make rule you need to escape the `$` so make passes them through to the shell. Editing to fix.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. To try it with a toy case, I did: `@ret=$$(ls); echo ret=-$$ret-`, but this stores in the variable the **result** of the command (here, the folder content), not its return value... I am not really sure how `make` treats this double expansion thing, so I tried `@ret=$$(ls); echo ret=-$(ret)-`. This gives an empty content. Any ideas ?

Comment: @kebs Wow, sorry, I clearly wasn't thinking about that one clearly. Editing again.